# Append Data to Existing Data with Current date In R Automation

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, tidyr

I have a CSV file which has two columns Name and Number, this CSV is getting generated daily, what i want is to have a single variable and append the data that i get everyday to this variable with current date for record purpose.
Needs to automate this process as its a Daily task.
What i did is below.

Suppose this is the first data

```
   name  number  
1    a      1    
2    b      2    
3    c      3    
4    d      4    
5    e      5    
6    f      6
```

added date to this data in this way

```
   df <- cbind(df,Date = march8)  //march8 has date of this day
```

After adding date

```
   name   number     Date
1    a      1    2018-05-08
2    b      2    2018-05-08
3    c      3    2018-05-08
4    d      4    2018-05-08
5    e      5    2018-05-08
6    f      6    2018-05-08
```

and Now i want to append another data of current date to this data

My New Data

```
   name  number 
1    l      3 
2    c      4 
3    a      5 
4    c      6 
5    d      4 
6    g      2
```

Again adding date.

```
df1 <- cbind(df1,Date = Sys.Date())
```

After adding date

```
  name number   Date
1    l      3  2018-05-09
2    c      4  2018-05-09
3    a      5  2018-05-09
4    c      6  2018-05-09
5    d      4  2018-05-09
6    g      2  2018-05-09
```

And Lastly

```
 df <- rbind(df,df1)
```

After Combining

```
     name number  Date
  1    a      1   2018-05-08
  2    b      2   2018-05-08
  3    c      3   2018-05-08
  4    d      4   2018-05-08
  5    e      5   2018-05-08
  6    f      6   2018-05-08
  7    l      3   2018-05-09
  8    c      4   2018-05-09
  9    a      5   2018-05-09
 10    c      6   2018-05-09
 11    d      4   2018-05-09
 12    g      2   2018-05-09
```

Doing this Everyday, is there a  better way to automate this whole process.
Hope i made my question clear and understandable and Sorry for posting such a long Question.

Thankyou.

Comment: I'm not sure what more automation you are trying to get at, as this seems like it is only a few lines of code to run each day. But for new days you could just run `df <- rbind(df,df1)` first and then replace the missing date value with `df$Date <- ifelse(is.na(df$Date),Sys.Date(),df$Date)`. However, this doesn't shorten your code in any way.

Comment: How do **rbind** will work without adding date first ,numbers of columns will no match with **df** and **df1** and there will be an error generated.

Answer (score 0):

If it is supposed to run in a server, try using something like Linux cron to call a bash script everyday. In the bash script you may call your Rscript to append the new data to the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Data and setting wd()

```
  xy = data.frame(Date = Sys.Date()-1, matrix(runif(5*6), ncol = 6))
  setwd(....)
```

writing for the first time using write.csv

```
  write.csv(xy,"data.csv", row.names=F)
```

Later, use write.table

```
  xy = data.frame(Sys.Date(), matrix(runif(5*6), ncol = 6))
  write.table(xy, file="data.csv", sep = ",", append = T, col.names = F, row.names=F)
```